# Android java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException HeaderViewListAdapter.java line

Tags: android

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 1
       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayLis`enter code here`t.java:255)
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
       at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:230)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2351)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1816)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:661)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5520)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3403)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3750)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3591)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7823)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2068)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2350)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2083)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2216)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1563)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2552)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2164)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8003)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4215)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3706)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3675)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3683)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3843)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3706)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3675)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3683)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5928)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5877)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5848)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6008)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5981)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6027)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You should explain what your problem is. Add a question and then we can try to help you.

Comment: I recently started seeing crash reports from Crashlytics with the following trace. don't know how to fixed it.

Comment: Did you got any success with the issue, as I am also facing the same issue and not able to fix it. Doesn't knew where it is happining.

Answer (score 0):

Your listitem inflation in the listview is throwing this. You are trying to access 5th element in your array list which only has a size of one. Instead of statically trying to get values, use listview dynamically by making use of the position field